# Rails update action not updating

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, ruby-on-rails-4

Trying to update the anonyminity of posts:

in the view

```
<%= form_for (post), remote: true do |f| %>
                            <%= f.check_box :anonymous %>
                            <span>Anonymous</span>
                            <%= f.submit 'Save' %>
                        <% end %>
```

the controller

```
def update
@post = Post.find(params[:id])
if @post.update_attributes(permit_post)
  puts 'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa'
  puts @post.anonymous === true
  puts 'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa'
  respond_to do |format|
   format.html
   format.js
  end
end
end
private 
def permit_post
params.require(:post).permit(:image, :title, :long, :anonymous, :facenumber);
end
```

in the console

```
    Started PATCH "/posts/9" for 94.187.88.109 at 2016-09-16 20:58:09 +0000
Processing by PostsController#update as JS
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "post"=>{"anonymous"=>"1"}, "commit"=>"Save", "id"=>"9"}
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ?  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 2]]
  Post Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "posts".* FROM "posts" WHERE "posts"."id" = ?  ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 1  [["id", 9]]
   (0.2ms)  begin transaction
   (0.1ms)  rollback transaction
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
   (0.1ms)  rollback transaction
  Rendered posts/update.js.erb (0.1ms)
Completed 200 OK in 150ms (Views: 22.4ms | ActiveRecord: 0.9ms)
```

there apears to be no error but the attributes are not updating.
Thanks for the help
**Update**
in the model

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
include PublicActivity::Common
cattr_accessor :current_user
cattr_accessor :user_id
acts_as_votable
has_attached_file :image, styles: { medium: "550", large: "600", thumb: "100x100>" }, default_url: "/missing.png"
validates_attachment_content_type :image, content_type: /\Aimage\/.*\Z/
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :category
validates :user_id, presence: true
validates :image, presence: true
has_many :comments
```

end

Comment: What's in `permit_post`?

Comment: @RSB updated the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me like validations are not passing. As you can see in the console, there's none of the puts evaluations you put, printed. Which means `update_attributes` is returning `false`.

Why don't you use `byebug`to put a breakpoint and evaluate `@post.errors.messages.inspect`, to check why it's not updating? Another option would be `Rails.logger.info(@post.errors.messages.inspect)` if you don't want to include byebug to your development gems. Of course, that need to be put after `@post.update_attributes` (where the `if` finishes)

Answer (score 0):

You are getting boolean values in `0` and `1` but `ruby` understands `true` and `false`. So you need to convert `1` to `true` and `0` to false before saving. You can do that in `Post` model like this

```
before_validation :convert_boolean

def convert_boolean
  self.anonymous = (anonymous != nil and anonymous != '0')      
end
```

To avoid this, alternatively you can pass `true`/`false` instead of `0`/`1` in params.

Try this

```
<%= f.check_box :anonymous, {}, true, false %>
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: added the model

Comment: still the same result, thanks for the continuous help

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123570/discussion-between-rsb-and-malek-zalfana).